# SQL Server query to Oracle query conversion

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to write a query in Oracle, but I'm more familiar with SQL Server.

In SQL Server, the query would look as follows: (simplified)

```
if exists (
    select * from table where a=1
)
begin
    update table set b=1 where a=1 
end else 
begin 
    insert table (a,b) values(1,1) 
end
```

Thanks for any help :)

===============================================================================

This is the Merge option, (I think):

```
MERGE INTO table T
USING (
    SELECT a,b
    FROM table
) Q
ON T.a = Q.a
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET T.a = 1
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT table (a,b) VALUES (1,1);
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Use the merge statement.

Comment: What does that mean? Can you give an example relating to the above SQL? Thanks

Comment: Stackoverflow can give plenty of them to you. ;) http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=oracle+merge

Comment: I added what I think is the right usage of `MERGE` - does this look right? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be the correct syntax for Oracle 11g. I'm not an expert on Oracle so maybe someone else could explain it better, but I believe the `dual` table is used when inserting new values instead or trying too merge is from another table.

```
MERGE INTO table1 T
USING (
    SELECT 1 a, 1 b FROM dual
) Q
ON (T.a = Q.a)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET b = 1
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (a,b) VALUES (Q.a,Q.b);
```

[Working example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/54404/1)